# How do I make issues private in Mantis?

Tags: mantis

In Mantis issue tracker is there any way to make only issues reported by a user himself visible to him? I want each reporter see his own issues.

I plan to allow end-user to report experienced issue, indeed I want to use mantis as a ticketing system.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that all issues reported by users with a `REPORTER` status are visible only to the reporter and users with `DEVELOPER` or better status, set

```
$g_default_bug_view_status = VS_PRIVATE;
```

To make sure that reporters can't alter the view status to make issues public set

```
$g_set_view_status_threshold = DEVELOPER;
```

This way, all issues will be private by default and developers can make them public if they choose to.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not address the question.

Comment: @PHPst - I may have missed the point, was private issues not what you were asking for?

Comment: The user's issue should be only visible for developers and himself by default. He should not be able to send public issues.

Comment: @PHPst - I see now, I updated my answer